# Visa Acceptance chance after federal government approval in Germany

Tags: germany

I have received the following replay from BVA :

processing of the application has ended at the Central Skilled Immigration Center Rhineland-Palatinate.

The embassy still has to process the application.

For further questions please contact the embassy.

But Embassy is taking long to process the application. Do i have acceptance chance?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "long," they may simply be overworked. But if the provincial authorities had given a clear no, there would not be much work for the embassy.

Comment: You have a chance until you get a refusal. No-one on this site can answer your question.